# How to vertically center a floating element

Tags: css, css-float

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
.container {
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 50px;
  verticle-algn: middle;
  clear: both;
}
.float {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="inside">inside</button>
  <button class="float">float</button>
</div>
```

Please check this example.I want the `.float` element to be vertically centered of the `.container` element as the `.inside` element.But no matter I trigger `BFC` or add a `pseudo element`, I can not clear the impact of the `float` element.I don't think margin is a best way to solve this.Can you tell me how to fix it, thanks for your help.

Comment: first get rid of float and check the duplicate for better way to place your element and align them

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work what you expected.

```css
* {
margin: 0px;
}
.container{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
background: #ccc;
line-height: 50px;
}
.float{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inside"><button>inside</button></div>
<div class="float"><button>float</button></div>
</div>
```